# How to add image in email template dynamically?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, images

I have a letterhead that I'll be using for different Email template.

On VF page, I have a button which will take the screenshot of the page and store in a rich text field in a custom object. The screenshot is handdled by the htmlcanvas JS framework.

I'm trying this rich text to include in the email template, but no success. Below is the example I used in the email template:

```
Hello, 

Below is the screenshot:

<apex:outputField value="{!objectname.RTFname__c}"/>
```

Upon sending the test email, I receive email with image not visible:

[image]

I also understood later upon small research that the image is not visible due to authentication as it's in external environment from [here](http://goo.gl/RZPAUp).

My requirement is simple; on click of the button on the VF, the image which saves in the RTF should be visible on the email template and on the external environment. Thanks in advance for the guidance.

Comment: If image is globally available then only image will be display.. So you may need to add the image into document and display that image. OR another I can think now to use image blob data..

Comment: @Ratan image currently comes from a RTF of a custom object. how can we dynamically insert and retrieve that image in a email template if document object is used and how do i use it if that's possible?

Comment: consider using a VF component in the VF email template that has its own controller (with some ID field passed to it from the VF email template)